# What the source of all those funny images used in trilogy sites?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, images

I'm talking about the pictures that are shown when human verification is due, or when something is wrong, like this one, at meta :

[image: Humans Are Dead]

Would you share the sources of some of those funny images?

Comment: I just got the human verification page, submitted the CAPTCHA text, closed the tab and saw the EXACT SAME IMAGE on my screen because this question was in the next tab.  Really threw me for a loop for a second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They all seem to be references stemming from [Flight of the Conchords (FOTC)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_of_the_Conchords) some more closely based than others. FOTC have a TV series that showed up on HBO and do live performances and the like.  [YouTube has a ton of videos for them.](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=flight+of+the+conchords&search_type=&aq=f)

Specifically Meta's image comes from [Jinx](http://www.jinx.com/men/shirts/video_games); Server Fault's image comes from [John W. Golden](http://www.johnwgolden.com/space.htm):

[image: Robot image]

And Super User's image might be Jeff himself???:

[image: Robot image]

Answer (score 1):

The first one was from [Flight of the conchords.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_of_the_conchords) This is too I think, there's a song by them called [Humans are dead.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WGoi1MSGu64)